# Relatively prime numbers from a list

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

In racket how can I create a procedure, using `filter` and `gcd`, which does the following:

`(list-of-numbers) number = > (list)`

Where the resulting list includes the numbers from the list that are relatively prime to the single one?

EDIT:
So far I've come up with  the following code:

```
(define (coprime? list-of-num n)
 (cond 
  [(empty? list-of-num) empty]
  [else
   (filter (lambda (num)
           (= (gcd (first list-of-num) n) 1)) num))]))
```

But I'm completely lost and realize that it's kind of a mess. My general idea is to make a boolean function that returns #t whenever `(gcd number-from-list number)` equals one and then the procedure filters every number from the list that results in #t.

Comment: You call `filter`, passing it the array and a function that calls `gcd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the definition of [relative primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers), and the solution follows naturally:

```
(define (relative-primes lst num)
  (filter (lambda (e)
            <???>) ; see definition of relative primes
          lst))
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean but please see my edit if it gives you a better clue about what I'm trying to achieve. Thank you.

Comment: @user2969733 what exactly is that you don't understand? my answer above is the correct solution, the code in the question is more complicated than it needs to be (you don't have to use `cond` here!). The only part that I left as an exercise is determining whether the current element `e` is coprime with the `num` parameter. Just replace the `<???>` with the correct code

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I figured it out with your help. I replaced <???> with `(= 1 (gcd num e))`. Apparently I have a tendency of needlessly overcomplicating. Thank you for offering this solution!